# How to retrieve multiple message in RabbitMQ callback?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using a rabbitmq in symfony framework to publish and consume the queue data. I successfully push the data into queue but while reading the data i'm having a issue. single message i can read easily but problem with the multiple message with callback.

I have create a design for consuming the queue using some service.

QueueService.php

```
class QueueService
{
protected $logger;
public function addInQueue($class, $data, $event,$isEnabled)
{
    $publishData = $this->getPublishData($class, $data, $event,$isEnabled);
    $this->queue->publish($publishData);
}

public function fetchInQueue()
{
    $this->logger->info(' fetchInQueue >>>>>>>>');
    $res = $this->queue->consume();
    $this->logger->info('received message >>>>>>>>'.print_r($res,true));
}
}
```

AMQPHelper.php

```
class AMQPHelper {

protected $conConfig;
protected $queueConfig;
protected $logger;
private $response;

public function __construct($conConfig, $queueConfig)
{
    $this->conConfig = $conConfig;
    $this->queueConfig = $queueConfig;
    $loggerHelper = new LoggerHelper();
    $this->logger = $loggerHelper->init('amqp-helper');
}
public function consume()
{

    $connection = new AMQPConnection(
        $this->conConfig['host'],
        $this->conConfig['port'],
        $this->conConfig['username'],
        $this->conConfig['password'],
        $this->conConfig['vhost']
    );
    $channel = $connection->channel();


    $channel->exchange_declare(
        $this->queueConfig['exchange'],
        'direct',
        false,
        true,
        false
    );
    $channel->queue_declare(
        $this->queueConfig['exchange'],
        false,
        true,
        false,
        false
    );
    $channel->queue_bind(
        $this->queueConfig['exchange'],
        $this->queueConfig['exchange'],
        $this->queueConfig['routing']
    );

    //Consume
    $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $channel->basic_consume(
        $this->queueConfig['exchange'],
        $this->queueConfig['routing'],
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        array($this,'getQueueMsg')
    );

    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $this->logger->info('  messages'.print_r($this->response,1));
        $this->logger->info('Waiting for incoming messages');
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $connection->close();
    $channel->close();

    return $this->response;
}

public function getQueueMsg(AMQPMessage $msg)
{
    $this->logger->info('Message body', print_r($msg, 1));
    $data = json_decode($msg->body, true);
    $this->response = $data;
}
```

I have write a console command to use QueueService function.I want all the queue return data in console command because after getting all queue data i want to re-run some console commands based on data.

ConsumeFailureCommand.php

```
class ConsumeFailureCommand extends BaseCommand{

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('consume-failure')
        ->setDescription('notification message consumer from RabbitMQ')
        ->addOption(
            'wait',
            null,
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'Wait for next message',
            1
        );
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
    $queueMng = $this->getContainer()->get('service_queue_management.queue_service');
    $this->setInput($input);
    $this->setOutput($output);
    $data = $queueMng->fetchInQueue();
    $this->logInfo(print_r($data,1));
}
```

}

so how the queue will return all data to service. It will return single message everytime but i want multidimension array of all data.

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle

Comment: i don't want to change the library because some existing code is written using old library.

Comment: This seems to me like a invalid request from queue standpoint. In my opinion, one message should not rely on existence of next one or previous one - it introduces a dependency which can be, well, glitchy. 

Have you considered sending those N messages as one big composite message?

Comment: @jovanPerovic when some console command fail i have push that data to message queue and message queue will read all those message and re-run the command based on action.

Comment: You have to read multiple times to get multiple messages. The `get` method returns zero or one message (depending on whether a message is on the queue), and there is no way or reason to have it do otherwise.